# Drools 7.4.1 kieservices.factory.get() returns null

Tags: drools, kie

I try to integrate Drools 7.4.1 into a webapp in tomcat.

When I call in the code the following statement to get a KieService I get `null`.

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
```

When the same method is being called from a test method it is ok.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Not all Drools jars on the web server?

Comment: Ι have these libs in the webapp

            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <artifactId>drools-templates</artifactId>

Answer (score 12):

You have to add `drools-compiler` in your dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the tip nicole.torres.

For this problem we can use the appendingtransformer avalaible in the maven-shade-plugin resource transformers:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer

Using this we can append all META-INF/kie.conf files. Anyone facing a null pointer when creating a KieBase or KieContainer in an ubber jar, visit this thread. I spent three days to find the solution and tried to create an ubber jar for almost every damn drools example available online :(

Comment: Thanks a lot. If anybody else is using a fat jar built with maven-shade-plugin this will fix it.

Answer (score 7):

We had the same issue when trying to use Drools in our webserver with 
embedded Grizzly http server.

We also needed to add the drools-compiler dependency, but that alone does not fix it.

Because there are multiple kie.conf files on the class path from the different dependencies, the uber-jar ends up having just one, and then definitions for classes to load are missing.

Besides these entries from the drools-core kie.conf:

```
org.kie.api.io.KieResources = org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl
org.kie.api.marshalling.KieMarshallers = org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.MarshallerProviderImpl
org.kie.api.concurrent.KieExecutors = org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl
```

we added these lines from drools-compiler to our uber-jar **kie.conf**:

```
org.kie.api.KieServices = org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl
org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService = org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl
```

Otherwise the KieServices were not loaded and KieServices.Factory.get() returned null.

We are modifying the built jar afterwards using

```
jar uf myjar.jar META-INF/kie.conf
```

to modify the contained kie.conf file. We couldn't find a clean integrated solution with Maven. Any suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Carlos Costa, below changes in pom.xml solved the issue.

Summarizing all suggestions, below is the detailed solution.
In pom.xml, add the following.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>${runtime.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <configuration>
            <transformers>
              <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/kie.conf</resource>
              </transformer>
            </transformers>
          </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: We did this and it worked.  The kie.conf file at first had 3 lines of properties.  After doing this it had about 25 (they all get combined).  O, and the Transformer needs to be added to the Shade plugin in the Execution section.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building using gradle and shadow jar, you can append the kie.conf files together by modifying the shadowJar task

```
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    transform(com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer) {
      resource = "META-INF/kie.conf"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this two dependencies and {version} of both dependencies must be the same

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
  <version>{version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>{version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest drools jar package version.

```
  <properties>
        <drools-version>7.16.0.Final</drools-version>
  </properties>
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening because you're using an uber-jar, as suggested by nicole.torres.

Another solution is to manually fetch the contents of all `META-INF/kie.conf` from your dependencies (i.e. drools-core, drools-compiler, etc) and add them into your project `src/main/resources/META-INF/kie.conf` file.

The advantage over the other solution is that you don't need to manually modify the JAR after packaging it.

If you're not using an uber-jar then the problem could be something else, since all the dependencies should be available at runtime.