# kieservices.factory.get() returns null in kie-api7.6.0

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am using kie-api 7.6.0.

When I am trying to get `kieservices.factory.get()` , its returning `null`.

My Java project is a gradle project.

What can be the cause? My Java project is a gradle project.

```
final ReleaseIdImpl releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl(RULE_PACKAGE, RULE_NAME,
            RULE_VERSION);
    final KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

    final KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);
```

I am getting ks as null and thus NullPointerException at ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);

I have added dependencies for the following jars

```
drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar
drools-core-6.5.0.Final.jar
drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final.jar
drools-jsr94-6.5.0.Final.jar
drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar
drools-templates-6.5.0.Final.jar
org.drools.eclipse-6.5.0.Final.jar
kie-maven-plugin-6.5.0.Final.jar
kie-api-6.5.0.Final.jar
kie-ci-6.5.0.Final.jar
kie-internal-6.5.0.Final.jar
```

Comment: please add some code or error description

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: please add you gradle dependencies: <dependency>...</dependency>

Comment: I have updated with the dependencies

Comment: Me too, same version, kieservices.factory.get() returns null, using Maven. Will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the same cause as here: [Drools 7.4.1 kieservices.factory.get() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556233/drools-7-4-1-kieservices-factory-get-returns-null)

Here is my answer.

---

We had the same issue when trying to use Drools in our webserver with 
embedded Grizzly http server.

We also needed to add the drools-compiler dependency, but that alone does not fix it.

Because there are multiple kie.conf files on the class path from the different dependencies, the uber-jar ends up having just one, and then definitions for classes to load are missing.

Besides these entries from the drools-core kie.conf:

```
org.kie.api.io.KieResources = org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl
org.kie.api.marshalling.KieMarshallers = org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.MarshallerProviderImpl
org.kie.api.concurrent.KieExecutors = org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl
```

we added these lines from drools-compiler to our uber-jar **kie.conf**:

```
org.kie.api.KieServices = org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl
org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService = org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl
```

Otherwise the KieServices were not loaded and KieServices.Factory.get() returned null.

We are modifying the built jar afterwards using

```
jar uf myjar.jar META-INF/kie.conf
```

to modify the contained kie.conf file. We couldn't find a clean integrated solution with Maven. Any suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to add the drools-compiler, drools-core dependency in pom.xml