# Using drools in a Spark job

Tags: java, apache-spark, drools, drools-kie-server

I am trying to use drools in spark job submitted to a cluster. THe job will start by getting the drools jar from a drools server then initialize the base and sessions. 
My code work when executed in Spark but when submitting to spark cluster a NPE happens.

This is how I am doing

```
String url = "{my server address}/drools-wb/maven2/com/myspace/Project1/1.0.0/Project1-1.0.0.jar";
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

//ERROR is in the below line 
ReleaseId releaseId = ks.newReleaseId("com.myspace", "Project1", "1.0.0"); 

KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource) ks.getResources().newUrlResource(url);
```

The error shown after submitting the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.opencell.spark.jobs.TestWithDrools.main(TestWithDrools.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-08-29 10:08:09 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
```

Do you have an idea about solving this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused because ks is null.

So to resolve this issue please refer to this post:

[Drools 7.4.1 kieservices.factory.get() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556233/drools-7-4-1-kieservices-factory-get-returns-null)