# Why does KieServices.Factory.get() returns null when used in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, jboss, drools

I'm using the `7.32.0.Final` version from maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add **implementation 'org.drools:drools-compiler:7.32.0.Final'** inside
   your **build.gradle** file.
2. A quickly test of this is by using **KieServices.Factory.get();** in
   your activity and see if has a value.
3. Unforntunately **KieServices.Factory.get();** always returns **null**.

Tips to keep in mind:

- When I create a Jboss Drool project with IntellijIDEA everything works fine.
- Unfortunately most samples are written in java with maven instead of gradle.
- The best sample from the owners is the following https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/drools-examples-android

Comment: The fact that most projects use Maven is not really an issue since it's nearly trivial to switch between the two build systems.

Comment: I don't know why but in a java project everything works fine, in Android I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556233/drools-7-4-1-kieservices-factory-get-returns-null